# Highcharts label formatter to query mysql?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I have the following code which displays an icon and link in the xaxis label

```
        formatter: function() {
            return '<a href="'+ categoryLinks[this.value] +'">'+
                this.value +'</a> <img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" />';
        }
```

[Complete jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/YhjBz/)

Can a condition be added to the formatter to check a mysql table and if a table field exists display the icon only instead of the icon/category name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatter is a function like any other, its purpose is to return a string to display but how it does that is up to you, so yes, it could do a roundtrip to the database and query a specific field. That functionality is not built into highcharts though.

I updated the example to show the idea of calling out to a separate function: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTXws/)

Comment: Thanks for the example fiddle